# Functions arcsin and arccos are not working properly

Tags: c++, equation

I need to write the code for solving a simple equation, which should contain arcsin and arccos.

Formulas

```
F = cos^2(p(x)) + sin^2(p(y) + p(z)
p(k) = arccos(a * k) + arcsin(k)
```

Here is the code I wrote for solving it, but it gives `-nan Ind` as output. However, when I fix `acos` and `asin` to just `cos` and `sin`, everything works.

Expected input:

```
x = 1.20
y = 3.05
z = 2.00
```

Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const double a = 0.01;

double p(double k) {
    double p1;
    p1 = acos(a * k) + asin(k);
    return (p1);
}

int main() {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double F;

    cout << "x = "; cin >> x;
    cout << "y = "; cin >> y;
    cout << "z = "; cin >> z;

    F = pow(cos(p(x)), 2) + pow(sin(p(y)), 2) + p(z);

    cout << "F = " << F << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are the values meant to be in degrees or radians?

Comment: Start by computing the same equation for some example values with a calculator. At each step, compare the values you obtain by hand to those your program produces at the same point.

Comment: Values are meant to be in radians

Comment: Mathematically, `arcsin` and `arccos` are only defined in the domain [-1, 1], because they are inverse operations to `sin` and `cos`. Your inputs are out of domain for those functions.

Comment: "Solving an equation" does not mean what you think it means. You're computing the value of a function.

Comment: What do you expect `asin(3.05)` to produce?   Because that is produced in the process of computing `p(y)`, when `y` is entered as `3.05`.    The `asin()` function only has defined values for arguments in the range `[-1,1]` - the result of an argument outside that range, like you are providing is implementation defined (although `NaN` is common in practice with floating point formats that support NaNs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OUTPUT range of SIN and COS is [-1, +1].  That means the INPUT range of ARC (inverse) sin is [-1, +1].  You are trying to do asin(1.2), which probably yields NaN.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: change your value of k to be [-1, +1].  I also recommend understanding trigonometry (not just programming).

Comment: @tensshhi *Why* do you want to use `arcsin`? `arcsin(x)` answer the question "What input do I need to give to `sin` to get `x`?". It makes no sense to input anything less than `-1` or more than `1` in it, becase `sin` can never never produce such values. What is the meaning of `x`, `y` and `z`? What should be the result of your program (i.e. what is the meaning of the equation you are calculating and what does the result mean)?

Comment: BTW, there are no units on the INPUT to `asin` (for those thinking radians vs. degrees).  Now there ARE units on the RETURN value of `asin`, it is RADIANS.